# Can I keep the hats?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash-2015

I would like to keep my hats for the rest of the year.

Or at least pick one to use.

I really liked this feature.

How I would do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I understand your pain, I secretly hate this site (of secretly cloned evil clowns)  and I think its best feature are the precious hats. How can I easily have more of them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope, [hat season is always temporary](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/faq) and they aren't a permanent feature on the site.

If you wanted to keep your hat then you should have taken a screenshot of your pic with a hat.

Answer (score -2):

Here you go:

[image]

[Source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gbdd.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gbdd.png)